# Import and using shape files Python and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapes

Im having trouble implementing my shape file into my python notebook.

It doesnt seem to be referencing my file even though the path location is correct.

```
import shapefile as shp
sf = shp.Reader("/Shape/mygeodata/northern-ireland")

#create figure to draw map and set its size
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,20))


#create map with the below code
m = Basemap(resolution='h', # c, l, i, h, f or None
            projection='merc',
            lat_0=0, lon_0=0,
            llcrnrlon=-8.239, llcrnrlat=53.9911, urcrnrlon=-5.3723, urcrnrlat=55.276)


#define how map is displayed
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#46bcec')
m.fillcontinents(color='#f2f2f2',lake_color='#46bcec')
m.drawcoastlines()


#for loop to plot the longitude and latitude of each crime
for i, row in crimeDataNI.iterrows():
        lat = row['Latitude']
        lon  = row['Longitude']
        x,y = m(lon, lat)
        m.plot(x, y, 'o', markersize=6, color='#444444', alpha=0.8)

#try and read in Northern Ireland police force boundaries 
m.readshapefile(sf, 'northern-ireland')
```

And i am getting the following error:

ShapefileException: Unable to open /Shape/mygeodata/northern-ireland.dbf or /Shape/mygeodata/northern-ireland.shp.

Comment: Do NOT post code as a screenshot. Please include both the code and the complete stack trace as properly formatted text!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referencing the file incorrectly.  Take a look at this tutorial https://chrishavlin.wordpress.com/2016/11/16/shapefiles-tutorial/  for an example on using shapefiles with MatPlotLib.

Also you might want to search https://gis.stackexchange.com for more help and pointers.